# Manipulate DOM of Angular directive from outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

### Scenario

```
<div>
    <my-directive id='item.id' ng-reqeat='item in items'></my-directive>
</div>
```

I want to manipulate DOM in `my-directive` after it is fully loaded. Obviously, controller can't be used in this because controller is initiated before DOM completed. I've came up with this solution.

### My solution

```
<div>
    <my-directive id='item.id' ng-repeat='item in items'></my-directive>
    <manipulator-directive></manipulator-directive>
</div>
```

JS

```
app.directive('manipulatorDirective', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function() {
            $timeout(function() {
                var element = $('#<id>');
                // code to manipulate the element
        }, 500);
    };
}]);
```

This is working. However, it seems this isn't proper way to achieve this job. If `my-directive` takes more than `500ms`, `manipulator-directive` is going to break.

### Questions

- Is there way to assure `link` function of `manipulator-directive` executing only after `my-directive` finishes its all tasks (`link`, adding to DOM)?
- Any different solution for this problem?

### Note

- I've tried `priority` when declaring both `my-directive` and `manipulator-directive`. It's not correct use in this case. Because it only works if putting many directives in same tag. For example:

  ```
    <div lower-priority-directive higher-priority-directive></div>
  ```

Comment: In almost all cases where you want to do direct DOM manipulation in angular, it is the wrong solution and you should step back and look if there is an elegant angular way of achieving what you want to do without bad design. What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to integrate Angular with jsPlumb but don't want to use some existing jsPlumb Angular directives because of lack of functionality and maintenance. Any suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how jsplumb works, sorry :-S

Comment: Are you wanting to manipulate the elment for myDirective or manipulatorDirective? What are you wanting to do to it and under what circumstances? There are ways to do what I think you're asking, but your question isn't entirely clear on what you're hoping to accomplish.

Comment: Ask I mentioned above, I want to manipulate elements for myDirective. manipulatorDirective is just my temporary solution. Ultimately, I want to manipulate elements in myDirective after it is fully loaded and added into DOM.